# How To Auto Add To /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: resolv.conf

On Ubuntu 10.04 Server, you can edit a file and it will automatically add a nameserver to the `/etc/resolv.conf` on boot. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop does not have this feature that I'm aware of, although perhaps I could be wrong.

See, as a web developer, I replace my localhost domain with "me.com" (since I never use me.com) in my `/etc/hosts` file. So, I can visit my own web server this way. But since my `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't have nameserver 127.0.0.1 in it, every lookup has to go out to my slow ISP DNS lookup and then back. So, I edit the file manually, but every time I reboot, the connection gets lost, and every time my ISP has troubles and my system renegotiates afterwards, I have to type this entry in again.

Oh, and I prefer that the nameserver 127.0.0.1 be first, not last.

Note without this entry, every connection to me.com is slow. With this entry, my connection to me.com is super fast.

Is there a way to automatically do this on boot?