# Why does my name resolution hit the DNS even with a hosts file entry?

Tags: 10.04, dns, hosts, resolv.conf

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS Desktop. Being a web developer, naturally I created a "me.com" in my `/etc/hosts` file. Unfortunately, my name resolution is going out to the DNS before first checking my local hosts entry and I can't figure out why.

The end result is that if my /etc/resolv.conf contains `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in there first, then I get a response back in my web browser from me.com (local) within less than a second. But if I don't have that entry, then my response takes sometimes as much as 5 seconds if my ISP is a little slow.

The problem was so troublesome that I actually had to [file a question here (and someone resolved it)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29286/how-to-auto-add-to-etc-resolv-conf) for how to automatically insert that entry into `/etc/resolv.conf`. But one of the users (@shellholic) here highly recommended (and commented back and forth with me about it) that I should file this question.

Do you know why my workstation's name resolution has to hit the DNS server first before hitting my `/etc/hosts` file entry? For now, I'm using the [resolv.conf trick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29286/how-to-auto-add-to-etc-resolv-conf).

Comment: You might try looking `/etc/nsswitch.conf` .  The entries on my system are a little non-obvious, but you could test lookups with only `files` as an option and see if that made a difference.

Comment: Yes, could you give us the output of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `cat /etc/host.conf`? Also: how are you testing this (through pinging, browser, packet sniffing etc)?

Comment: To complete version of @arrange, could you attach the result of `time getent hosts me.com; hostname --fqdn; grep 'me.com' /etc/hosts; grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf; netstat -uln | grep ':53'; cat /etc/host.conf; wc -l /etc/hosts`. Don't hesitate to obfuscate rationality.

Comment: @shellholic ^rationality^rationally?  heh.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: indeed

Comment: My host.conf shows "order hosts,bind". My nsswitch.conf shows "hosts:files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4". I still need to do a time test following @shellholic's request. Just tight on time today.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` will let you reconfigure the order of the name resolution. By default, the host file is the first, then the configured DNS. There could be more options.

The file `/etc/hosts` only lists IP addresses and hostnames (multiple names for one IP if you want)

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` will list the default search domains, and will also list in sequence the name servers to use.

Comment: Also keep in mind that once a name is resolved by an application or a service on your Linux box, it will remain in cache for a duration known as the TTL (time to live). So if you switch the resolution sequence, you are better restart your system or clear any cache.

Comment: how do you clear the 'cache'?

Comment: I am not sure, but restarting a network connection with ifup and ifdown commands could do it. Of course, rebooting should clear the cache, but we are using Linux, right ?

Comment: `nscd` can cache name resolution queries, but [does not respect ttl](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656014) (and is therefore hosts caching is disabled by default). `systemd-resolved` will also cache entries. If none of those are configured, [Linux hosts do not cache DNS responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021207/1837991). (Browsers likely do at the application layer though)