# Network Manager discards changes to /etc/resolv.conf on boot

Tags: 11.04, network-manager, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Auto Add To /etc/resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29286/how-to-auto-add-to-etc-resolv-conf)

I wrote interfaces entries manually because of weird behaviour from network manager/indicator:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Also, I manually edited /etc/resolv.conf and added some DNS servers there, but on every boot it replace my edits with:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I would like to preserve my DNS host modifications to /etc/resolv.conf.  How can I do this?

Comment: I doubt you want to prevent that. You need to provide more details to allow us to help you with your dns setup: What are you trying to achieve that the standard setup does not do for you?

Comment: I wrote interfaces entry manually because of wierd behaviour from network manager: zz@zz-desktop:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.1
also, i manually edit /etc/resolv.conf and add some dns server there, but on every boot it replace my edits with zz@zz-desktop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver 127.0.0.1

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip and http://askubuntu.com/questions/29286/how-to-auto-add-to-etc-resolv-conf

Comment: one more: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip